# How to mark the y-values of data points in a given ggplot object?

Tags: r, ggplot2, sjplot

I'm trying to annotate the y-values of data points in a ***given*** ggplot object, after the fact.

To have a reproducible example, I'll create a model on `mtcars` data, using `lm()`, and plot using `sjPlot::plot_model()`.

```r
library(magrittr)
library(sjPlot)

given_p_object <- 
  mtcars %>% 
  lm(mpg ~ as.factor(gear), data = .) %>% 
  sjPlot::plot_model(., type = "pred")
```

---

So my question starts here: say that I'm given the object `given_p_object`. I execute it and get the plot:

```r
> given_p_object
```

[image: given_plot]

Is it possible to mark the y-values for each point on the plot, **without** referring back to the original data and the process that led to the plot (thus ignoring `mtcars %>% lm() %>% sjPlot::plot_model()`)? In other words, how can I extract from within the current `given_p_object` the information needed to do the following?
[image: demo]

Answer (score 1):

Those values can be found in :

```
given_p_object$gear$data$predicted
#[1] 16.1 24.5 21.4
```

A general solution would be :

```
get_predicted_value <- function(p) p[[1]]$data$predicted
get_predicted_value(given_p_object)
#[1] 16.1 24.5 21.4
```

Comment: Thank you, that's useful. Can I generalize this, such that for any given ggplot object `p`, I could get the y-values for data points? I'm asking because here we need to specify `gear`. I'm trying to be completely ignorant about the plot when pulling out the y-values.

Comment: Updated the answer to include a function to work with any `p` object.

Comment: Sorry if this gets annoying, but from this I'm understanding that there isn't a universal way to get the y-values? Consider, for example, `g <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point()`. Then `get_predicted_value(g)` returns `NULL`.

Comment: Hmmm...Sorry I am not aware of a general solution where it can return y-values from any plot. Would you expect the y-values to be returned from this plot as well? `plot(1:10, 11:20)`

Comment: No, because it's not a ggplot object. `blah <- plot(1:10, 11:20)` `is.ggplot(blah)` returns `FALSE`.